# SOAP in PHP. How do I get a return?

Tags: php, web-services, api, soap, wsdl

So, I'll just come right out and say I an fairly new to SOAP.

I've done PHP for quite some time, and XML, but never actually made anything with WSDL and SOAP. So here's goes (hopefully this isnt too stupid).

I have a WSDL file I want to request something from. 
Ex: http://whateverservice.org/?wsdl

And I want to do a simple API call for a job called "JobAPI_CheckConnection".
Using SoapUI, this is the SOAP code I get when looking at that job:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas/xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <tem:JobAPI_CheckConnection/>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So, how would I translate that into PHP?
From looking at this tutorial: http://devzone.zend.com/2202/php-and-soap-first-steps/

I get some of it, but not all...
From what I can gather so far, my PHP code should look somewhat similar to this:

```
<?php
$wsdl = "http://whateverservice.org/?wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$result = $client->JobAPI_CheckConnection();

echo $result->JobAPI_CheckConnectionResult;
?>
```

But this returns nothing, and the site fails to load. In other words, something is obviously wrong. In the tutorials I have seen so far, you send a request as well as a paramter to get a response, but this one, you just have to call on that job, and I would somewhat expect a result from that, but I have no clue how...

Anyone that either would be so willing as to point me in the right direction a tutorial or similar. Or if anyone would just come right out and give me the answer, that's cool, I just hope I can learn from it.

***Sidenote:** I am also not sure if I need to log in on the service I am connecting too, but if so, I honestly have next to no clue how... I assume it would be an array or parameter added to the "newSoapClient" call, but how and where, I dont know...*

Thanks for taking care of a noobie!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should look to the [native PHP SoapClient class](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.soapclient.php).

Then if you like using PHP objects and structured programming, I would advise you to use a WSDL to php generator that eases the way you create a request and receive the response. To do so, take a look to the [WsdlToPhp](https://github.com/mikaelcom/WsdlToPhp) project that you can use online at https://www.wsdltophp.com

Comment: Yes I am spending alot of time on reading up on this at the moment, and I am making some headway (though very slowly).

Now I have the issue that I for some reason cannot connect to the WSDL file. And whenever I do a try and catch it basically tells me it cannot find the WSDL file on localhost, but I dont get why it looks for it on localhost when I specify a location for the WSDL file?

As for the wsdltophp.com generator, yeah that would've been awesome,  but it costs money to get anything generated. Not that I expect anything really for "free", but not sure I wanna throw 24 euros on it...

Comment: You can use freely the online tool if the WSDL is not private. The other solution is that you download the project from Github then execute it on your own server. Can you tell the WSDL file path ?

Comment: That's the problem... The WSDL file is not "public" in that sense... It's a public API, but the server running it is on a closed network, so I cant link to it no...

But I believe I've solved it now. Now I face a different challenge with passing a nested array (I believe) in the SOAP call.

See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110020/how-to-use-two-arrays-in-one-php-call-to-wsdl-with-soap